# When you get 2 sets of bad luck dice (6 total frowns), can you discard 2 cards from the same stack?

Tags: cv

The rules say

> For every 3 bad luck symbols which a player has .... he must choose and discard one active (lying on top) card from their CV

Does this mean he can discard a card, then consider the card underneath active, then discard that one? Or, does he need to discard only cards that were active before beginning the discard process (i.e. cards from different stacks)?

Comment: Funny @joey I hadn't played this gam in more than a year now, but chjecking the rules to answer your question put it back on my radar so we played a game this afternoon ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have this game in French.

the rules say:

> Si un joueur possède 3 symboles Malchance sur un tirage de dés et/ou avec ses jetons, il doit immédiatement se défausser d'une de ses cartes CV actives.

This would translate as (emphasis mine):

> If a player has 3 bad luck symbols on his dice and/or tokens he must **immediately** discard one of his active CV cards

So, if you get your 6 bad luck symbols during the same turn but not on the same roll, I would say that you discard a card when you roll your third bad luck symbol and then a second one (from the same column if you wish) when you roll your sixth one. Assuming you get the 6 bad luck symbols at the same time (now that's real bad luck) I would appply the same rule and allow discarding twice from the same column...

Comment: The US rules have 3 items described for a player's turn, the resolution of the 3 bad luck symbols being the 3rd item (and the second being to select the cards to buy).  Is this how it's ordered in the french version? There's no mention of immediately discarding in the US version, so without that my interpretation would be that ordered items in a turn description happen one after the other (unless clearly stated or implied otherwise).

Comment: There are 5 steps in a turn in my rules booklet (with rough translations afterwards):
1) Lancer les dés (Roll the dice)
2) Acquérir des cartes (Get Cards)
3) Coup du sort ! (Bad Luck)
4) Enrichir son CV (Improve one's resume)
5) Remplacement des cartes (changing cards)